# git branch development or master for main branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

We currently have 3 branches in our git-repository. Those are development, staging and master, whereas staging had been created from master and development from staging. There's another git-setting, which is **main branch**. On the one hand it feels weird to set the main branch not to master, but on the other hand it would give all developers an easy manner of quickly cloning development repositories. A development-branch as main branch would also reduce the risk of mistakenly pushing changes to the master-branch.

Is it a best practice to set the main branch to development or to master?

Comment: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ Here is a good git branching model, hope this will help. This allow to keep the master branch super clean

Comment: @Epitouille thanks for the nice model on branching. However, this hadn't been my question. I was looking for the best practice for the **main branch**, which isn't the same as **master branch**